# SoundCloud JS API - Can I login everyone with the same account?

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm writing an application that allows users to upload sounds anonymously. Therefore, I'd like to authenticate with a single account, and upload all sounds to that account, rather than having the user login to their SoundCloud account and upload sounds under their account, which would break the anonymity. Is this possible with the existing API, or does the user have to login with their own SoundCloud account?

Comment: Technically this should work. But ensure that each uploader is aware that he is giving you the rights to each individual track - if the user was not informed proplery, it would be a violation against the https://soundcloud.com/community-guidelines - more details you will find here: https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the info. Definitely there will be notice.

Comment: Actually, I still don't see how this is supported between the `/connect` and `/oauth2/token` endpoints. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant information on authenticating without SoundCloud connect (ie: for a single user) is located here:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#user-credentials